# How to pass a regex when finding a directory path in bash?

Tags: command-line, bash, scripts

I have written a small bash script to find if a directory named `anaconda` or `miniconda` in my user `$HOME`. But it does not find the `miniconda2` directory in my home.

How could I fix this?

```
if [ -d "$HOME"/"(ana|mini)conda[0-9]?" ]; then
    echo "miniconda directory is found in your $HOME"
else
    echo "anaconda/miniconda is not found in your $HOME"
fi
```

P.S: If I have `[ -d "$HOME"/miniconda2 ]; then`, then it finds the miniconda2 directory so I think error lies in the part `"(ana|mini)conda[0-9]?"`

I want the script to be general. For me, it's miniconda2 but for some other user it might be anaconda2, miniconda3 and so on.

Comment: Another user might use anaconda_2 or -2 or -may2019. So wouldn't xxxconda* be better?

Comment: Bash filename expansion uses glob expressions, not regexes.

Answer (score 14, accepted):

This is a surprisingly tricky thing to do nicely.

Fundamentally, `-d` will only test a single argument - even if you could match filenames using a regular expression.

One way would be to flip the problem around, and test directories for a regex match instead of testing the regex match for directories. In other words, loop over *all* the directories in `$HOME` using a simple shell glob, and test each against your regex, breaking on a match, finally testing whether the `BASH_REMATCH` array is non-empty:

```
#!/bin/bash

for d in "$HOME"/*/; do
  if [[ $d =~ (ana|mini)conda[0-9]? ]]; then
    break;
  fi
done

if ((${#BASH_REMATCH[@]} > 0)); then
    echo "anaconda/miniconda directory is found in your $HOME"
  else
    echo "anaconda/miniconda is not found in your $HOME"
fi
```

An alternate way would be to use an extended shell glob in place of the regex, and capture any glob matches in an array. Then test if the array is non-empty:

```
#!/bin/bash

shopt -s extglob nullglob

dirs=( "$HOME"/@(ana|mini)conda?([0-9])/ )

if (( ${#dirs[@]} > 0 )); then
  echo "anaconda/miniconda directory is found in your $HOME"
else
  echo "anaconda/miniconda is not found in your $HOME"
fi
```

The trailing `/` ensures that only directories are matched; the `nullglob` prevents the shell from returning the unmatched string in the case of zero matches.

---

To make either recursive, set the `globstar` shell option (`shopt -s globstar`) and then respectively:-

- (regex version): `for d in "$HOME"/**/; do`
- (extended glob version): `dirs=( "$HOME"/**/@(ana|mini)conda?([0-9])/ )`

Comment: I'd go the array route. You can use `?([0-9])` in place of `@(|[0-9])` -- `?(...)` matches zero or one, same as the regex `?` quantifier.

Comment: You don't even need extglob is you use brace expansion (this generates all possible matching names): `~/{ana,mini}conda{0..9}*/`

Comment: Is there anyway to edit either of  these solutions so that it will hold **even** if `mini` or `anaconda` is installed in `$HOME/sub-directories`? For example `$HOME/sub-dir1/sub-dir2/miniconda2`

Comment: @Jenny For searching subdirectories, take [PerlDuck's solution](https://askubuntu.com/a/1147709/301745) and simply remove the `-maxdepth 1`.

Comment: Hi wjandrea: Yes, I've done that too. But I wanted to know if there is a similar solution for these answers

Comment: Thanks @glennjackman - incorporated

Comment: @Jenny please see my edit concerning `globstar`

Comment: @xenoid I considered using brace expansion; however I couldn't think of a way to do the equivalent of RE `[0-9]?` - the naive way would be to make that a brace expansion as well i.e. `{,[0-9]}` however that introduces a gotcha: the expanded list now contains a string with no glob characters, which does not undergo filename expansion and hence gets inserted into the array literally (bypassing the `nullglob`).

Comment: @steeldriver you might also want to use `dirs=( "$HOME"/@(ana|mini)conda*([0-9])/ )` to also match `miniconda123`.

Comment: @terdon yeah I didn't really want to go down the rabbit hole of what's the "right" thing to match - I just took the OP's regex as-is for the purpose of illustrating a general approach

Answer (score 9):

Indeed, as already mentioned, this is tricky. My approach is the following:

- use `find` and its *regex* capabilities to 
  find the directories in question.
- let `find` print an `x` for each found directory
- store the `x`es in a string
- if the string is non-empty, then one of the directories was found.

Thus:

```
xString=$(find $HOME -maxdepth 1 \
                     -type d \
                     -regextype egrep \
                     -regex "$HOME/(ana|mini)conda[0-9]?" \
                     -printf 'x');
if [ -n "$xString" ]; then
    echo "found one of the directories";
else
    echo "no match.";
fi
```

Explanation:

- `find $HOME -maxdepth 1` finds everything below `$HOME`
  but restricts the search to one level (that is: it doesn't
  recurse into subdirectories).
- `-type d` restricts the search to only `d`irectories
- `-regextype egrep` tells `find` what type of *regular
  expression* we deal with. This is needed because things
  like `[0-9]?` and `(…|…)` are somewhat special and `find`
  doesn't recognize them by default.
- `-regex "$HOME/(ana|mini)conda[0-9]?"` is the actual
  *regular expression* we want to lookout for
- `-printf 'x'` just prints an `x` for every *thing*
  that satisfies the previous conditions.

Comment: When there is a match. `-bash: -regex: command not found
found one of the directories`

Comment: Hi PerlDuck: Thanks. A nice answer too. But I get an error for `printf` For example when I run the script, it runs ok but it doesn't find the printf command when there is no match but I think it's because there is nothing to print may be?. `-bash: -printf: command not found
no match.`

Comment: @Jenny You may have made a typo when copying it, since it works fine for me. `-printf` is not a command but an argument to `find`. That's what the backslash at the end of the previous line does.

Comment: I'd suggest `-quit` after printing the found path, unless you *want* to keep going to detect ambiguity.

Comment: And why not print the actual path? You have it already, so it seems a shame to discard it and use `x` instead: `foundDir=$(find $HOME -maxdepth 1 -type d -regextype egrep -regex "$HOME/(ana|mini)conda[0-9]?" -print -quit); echo "found $foundDir"`

Comment: Yes @terdon, that's also possible. I just wanted to show the general idea. The OP may change the code according the their needs. I'm so used to that `-printf x` thing because it is the fastest and most reliable way to count files that satisfy a certain condition (far better than any `…|wc -l` approach).

Answer (score 2):

You can loop over a list of directory names you want to test and act on it if one of them exists:

```
a=0
for i in {ana,mini}conda{,2}; do
  if [ -d "$i" ]; then
    unset a
    break
  fi
done
echo "anaconda/miniconda directory is ${a+not }found in your $HOME"
```

This solution obviously doesn’t allow for the full regex power, but shell globbing and brace expansion is equal at least in the case you showed. The loop exits as soon as one directory exists and unsets the previously set variable `a`. In the subsequent `echo` line, the [parameter expansion](https://wiki.bash-hackers.org/syntax/pe#use_an_alternate_value) `${a+not }` expands to nothing if `a` is set (= no dir found) and “not ” else.

Answer (score 1):

Possible work around is searching miniconda and anaconda separately as shown below

```
if [ -d "$HOME"/miniconda* ] || [ -d "$HOME"/anaconda* ]; then
    echo "miniconda directory is found in your $HOME"
else
    echo "anaconda/miniconda is not found in your $HOME"
fi
```

But if someone has suggestions, I'd like to know why we cannot pass a regex when searching for directories.

Comment: I upvoted this - but then realized it will break if the user has more than one matching directory (e.g. miniconda AND miniconda2)

Comment: @steeldriver: "it will break if the user has more than one matching directory" Yes, thats's indeed true. Do you have any suggestions how to fix it?

Comment: @Jenny Use an array, like in steeldriver's answer. `shopt -s nullglob; dirs=( "$HOME"/miniconda* "$HOME"/anaconda* ); if (( ${#dirs[@]} > 0 )); then ...`

Comment: If you replace `] || [` with `-o` it at least shouldn’t break if both directories are found as both directory globs are looked for in the same test.

Comment: @steeldriver and Jenny: you might *want* it to break on ambiguity instead of just picking one.  Make the user specify their directory instead of maybe picking the wrong one.  (e.g. edit the script to set the dir name instead of running the auto-detection code.)