# Use of * in a pathway to a file using FNIRT

Tags: command-line, bash, scripts

I'm currently trying to make a bash script which automatically registrates PET-images to standard space (MNI152) using a T1 weighted MRI as reference. I use the example for functional to MNI152 on https://fsl.fmrib.ox.ac.uk/fsl/fslwiki/FNIRT/UserGuide#Example_uses. The bet and 2 flirts work, but then when I try to FNIRT it gives me Image exception #22 en #63, which are 'no image files match' and 'failed to read volume'. I use this command line for FNIRT:

```
fnirt --in=/home/mrstats/maxjoo/Dataset_fsl/ADNI/${subjid}/MPRAGE/*/*/${subjid}_MPRAGE_crop_brain.nii.gz --aff=affine_${subjid}.mat --cout=${subjid}_nonlinear_transf_1mm --ref=/opt/fsl/6.0.3/data/standard/MNI152_T1_1mm_brain.nii.gz
```

The problem here is the use of * in the '--in=' command as a way to select all folders in that directory. When I type the folder name itself it does not have these errors, but for me to be able to registrate my whole dataset in which the folders now referenced to as * have different names I need to find a way for the script to select each of these folders in the same way. I thought that * would be appropriate here but it isn't unfortunately.

Does someone know what I could do here or what I could replace * with for the script to actually work?

Comment: It depends on what fnirt accepts as input. Using a '*' means you need a procedure that opens -each- of the *'s and have it fetch all files. In python: `glob.glob('/home/mrstats/maxjoo/Dataset_fsl/ADNI/${subjid}/MPRAGE/*')` where you traverse all the results and filter on `${subjid}_MPRAGE_crop_brain.nii.gz` on the results of the 1st bit.

Comment: Thank you for your reply! I think I kinda understand what you mean, although it's not exactly clear for me yet. Could you maybe elaborate a bit more on this? Thanks a lot!

Comment: Welcome to AskUbuntu, perhaps this might help https://askubuntu.com/questions/1147681/how-to-pass-a-regex-when-finding-a-directory-path-in-bash